# how to get number with regex in text with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have urls  like these

> string1 = "/drupal-7.24/flag/unflag/share/**19**?destination=node/19&token=B7fveLPDve16HpNvL0K28olhaluOw4I-KZruie7vWfI";
>
> string2 = "/drupal-7.24/flag/unflag/post/**23**?destination=node/19&token=B7fveLPDve16HpNvL0K28olhaluOw4I-KZruie7vWfI";

how can I fetch the digits end path and before url query  (after last **/** and before **?**, in here 19 and 23)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression like this:

```
var reg = /(\d+)\?/;
var num1 = string1.match( reg );
if ( num1 ){
  // matched number is in num1[ 1 ]  
}
```

The regex is using the digit character class `\d` in a capture group - that's the surrounding parenthesis - followed by a literal question mark `\?`.

Once you have extracted your number, remember that it is still a string. You would need to use `parseInt` or something similar to convert it into an actual number.

Comment: text="/drupal-7.24/flag/flag/share/19?destination=node/19&token=B7fveLPDve16HpNvL0K28olhaluOw4I-KZruie7vWfI"; arr=text.match('/(\d*)\?/');
            console.log(arr); this returns me null and and undifinded !!!

Comment: What you pass into the [`match()` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) is not a string.. It should be a regular expression object. Note that I'm not using quotes to wrap it. `arr=text.match(/(\d*)\?/); `

Comment: ok. but it return me 2 value , 19? and 19 !!!, why?

Comment: @zhilevan - Take a look at the documentation for the match function. The first element is **all the matched text** and after that come the elements that were captured individually by the capture groups.

Answer (score 2):

```
digits = parseInt(string1.replace(/^.*\/(\d+)\?.*$/, '$1'), 10)
```

Explanation of the [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions):

- `^` = beginning of the string
- `.*\/` = anything until the last `/`
- `(\d+)\?` = a series of digits until the first `?`, captured as "`$1`"
- `.*$` = anything else until the end of the line (`$`)

The above will be replaced with:

- `$1` = the series of digits captured above

The result will be a string containing the digits you're interested in. [`parseInt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) will then convert the string to a [`Number`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number).

Comment: I try 
text="/drupal-7.24/flag/flag/share/19?destination=node/19&token=B7fveLPDve16HpNvL0K28olhaluOw4I-KZruie7vWfI";
parseInt(text.replace(/^.*\/(\d+)\?.*$/, '$1'), 10);
console.log($1); return null to me!!!

Comment: @zhilevan, `parseInt()` returns the number. Example updated.

Comment: thank you for your attention, I got my answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
var str = "/drupal-7.24/flag/unflag/post/23?destination=node/19&token=B7fveLPDve16HpNvL0K28olhaluOw4I-KZruie7vWfI";

var patt = new RegExp("\/([0-9]*)\\?");

var res = patt.exec(str);

alert(res[1]);
```

sorry about that!

Comment: jquery !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! not php

Comment: I never knew jQuery could run PHP code... cool...

Comment: haha damn - will ammend!

Comment: any chance of a none down-vote now? seeing as I actually showed how to do it in javascript this time not php :-P